# In Rails whats the best way to pass parameters on-click to a controller for use in ActiveCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am fairly new to Rails and am working on setting up a website with multiple buttons.  When one user clicks a button, that button should change colors on all other users pages using ActionCable.  I have this working but the way I'm passing the data from the view to the controller seems incorrect for just clicking an element.
What I have in my view right now is:
`<%= button_to MY_PATH, method: :put, params: {MY_KEY: "MY_VALUE"} do%>` 
`<span> MY_TEXT </span>` 
`<% end %>`
While this is working it forces me to wrap my actual element in a button, and re-style the button element itself. `link_to` is another option, but it seems to only make passing parameters to the controller more difficult.  Is there a more straightforward way to pass basic non-user dependent parameters to the controller without using a form?

Comment: You could do it with [`AJAX`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/). But there's nothing wrong with your button (though I'd use `:post` instead of `:put`)

Comment: `link_to` with `remote: true` should be as simple as your button.